# Windows TCP socket connection using VB.net on Linux

Tags: linux, vb.net, sockets, tcp

The goal is an vb.net connection between windows and linux.

**windows-server (vb.net):** The server should listen on port 4001/tcp for connections and do something with the packets.

```
Dim serverstream As NetworkStream
Dim serverstreamw As StreamWriter
Dim serverstreamr As StreamReader
Dim Server As TcpListener
Dim serverclient As New TcpClient
Dim ipendpoint As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4001)
Dim mainthread As Threading.Thread

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mainthread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf mainserver)
    mainthread.Start()
End Sub

Sub mainserver()
    Try
        Server = New TcpListener(ipendpoint)
        Server.Start()
        serverclient = Server.AcceptTcpClient
        serverstream = serverclient.GetStream
        serverstreamr = New StreamReader(serverstream)
        serverstreamw = New StreamWriter(serverstream)
        While True
            Select Case serverstreamr.ReadLine
                Case "onl" '........
                Case "logoff" '........
                Case "iamhere" '........
                    MessageBox.Show("WORKS!!!")
            End Select
        End While
    Catch

    End Try
End Sub
```

**linux-client:** The client should create an connection with the server and send him packets.

```
echo "iamhere" > /dev/tcp/client.ip/4001
```

**The problem is that it seems like the server does not open port 4001/tcp. The client gets no connection :/**

**How to fix that?**

Comment: Are you connecting over LAN or over the internet? If the latter you must port forward port 4001 in your router. Also I don't see you specify what IP to connect _**to**_ on linux.

Comment: Internet. Is there no other way than forwarding? How e.g. games handle this? U do not forward every port in ur router there :)

Comment: `IPAddress.Any` says to listen on all connections, doesn't it? So it needs to listen on all IP's bc of various clients :)

Comment: The _**server**_ must almost always port forward unless it uses [**hole punching**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) (advanced!). The _**client**_ usually mustn't as _outgoing_ connections are usually automatically opened in the NAT filter.

Comment: I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Read more about NAT: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Comment: `I'll give it a try :)` - Not Hole punching I presume, because it requires an external server which's router also must allow incoming connections. The best is to just forward port 4001 in your current server application's router.

Comment: Works perfect :)

Comment: After one time `echo "iamhere" > /dev/tcp/client.ip/4001` the messagebox `WORKS!` does not appear again, any idea to fix it? :)

Comment: Does that Linux code create a _**new**_ connection or does it use the current one?

Comment: It should create a new one using that. May we can reopen the port connection on the server after?

Comment: Wrote an answer. Also, when I said earlier that a server must almost always port forward I was referring to _**any**_ kind of server (games, applications, you name it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148623/discussion-between-visual-vincent-and-realksmc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the connection doesn't work is because you've got to [**forward port 4001**](http://portforward.com) in the server's router. Currently it is dropped by the router because the port is not mapped in the router's [**NAT**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) table, so the router does not know to which LAN device it should send the packet.

As for the message box only being shown once, if that Linux code of yours creates a ***new*** TCP connection then you gotta change your code to discard old connections after receiving a message:

```
 Try
    Server = New TcpListener(ipendpoint)
    Server.Start()
    While True 'Moved While up here to wait for new connections after every command.
        serverclient = Server.AcceptTcpClient
        serverstream = serverclient.GetStream
        serverstreamr = New StreamReader(serverstream)
        serverstreamw = New StreamWriter(serverstream)
        Select Case serverstreamr.ReadLine
            Case "onl" '........
            Case "logoff" '........
            Case "iamhere" '........
                MessageBox.Show("WORKS!!!")
        End Select
        serverclient.Close() 'Close old connection.
    End While
Catch
End Try
```

The reason we do this is because if Linux starts a new connection and the server doesn't, then the server will still be waiting for data on the old connection which isn't used anymore by Linux.

Comment: Fantastic :) Thx for ur time. Didn't thought it's that easy... just port forwarding. I am really thankful for ur answer ;)

Comment: @realKSMC : Glad I could help! Just keep in mind that you must change your code _**back**_ to what it was before if you some time are to connect with a client that keeps using _**the same**_ connection. -- Good luck!

Comment: Do e.g. new games tunneling the port connections so that no port forwarding in the router is needed? The client also receives packets from the server.

Comment: @realKSMC : _**Receiving packets**_ is not a problem _once a connection has been established_, but most games actually _**do not**_ implement hole punching as it is not a common thing to do. It is easier to let the server hosts forward the port(s) in their router.

Comment: I'll add the opposite form as an answer. May u can help me there too. So the client is windows and linux is the server. Port 4001 is open, but also no connection. Have a look at below soon :)

Comment: @realKSMC : Don't add it as an answer. Let us instead take this discussion in chat. One sec... (See comment on question)